# Issues with the connection between the MS Access database and Dataverse/SharePoint List

Tags: database, ms-access, linked-list, sharepoint-list, dataverse

I'm having an issue with a Microsoft Access connection. I have a Python code that exports a table to an Access database. When it is not linked to any other source such as Dataverse or a SharePoint list, it successfully exports the data. The problem arises when the database is linked to these destinations, and it generates the following error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find installable ISAM. (-1056) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Here it is my string connection:

```
dsn = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\WSInterface1.accdb;'
```

I have already installed the specified 64-bit driver, and I'm using a corporate user. Does anyone have any indication of what might be happening?

I tried to reinstall my MS Access driver connection, but it still didn't work.

My string connection from Access to Dataverse is:

```
OData 4.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;DATASOURCE_CLASS=Dataverse;ACCDB=YES;
```